# How to convert a point to polygon?

Tags: polygon, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a big data in GeoJSON with Point type like this:

```
    {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          2.8125,
          47.040182144806664
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          14.765625,
          48.69096039092549
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As far as I know, in order to create polygon on a map, my GeoJSON should have Polygon as a Type instead of Points. How can I do it? Does anybody have idea? Should I convert them into polygon? How? I really need your help guys... (I am using Mapbox-Gl-Js by the way)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to convert the points into polygons? Don't you just want to render them as circles or icons/markers?

Comment: Because I want to have polygons on my map instead of points and style them accordingly

Comment: I still don't really understand what you mean by converting a point into a polygon. Maybe a circle around each point? http://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer

Comment: I want to have polygon like this: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/ but in my geojson i have Point instead of Polygon

Comment: That's like saying you wish you had a car, but you have a bike, how can you convert your bike into a car? Go and get yourself some polygon data if you want polygons. If you only have point data, you have to draw points.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The problem is my data is too big and unique so that's why Im looking for a way of converting...

Comment: I don't know if we're just speaking a different language or what, but I still have no idea what you expect to happen in taking a point and somehow turning it into a polygon.

Comment: Oh...I see from your answer below that you want to do region-mapping, using an attribute from each point, and the geometry from a region like a country. Well, there isn't really a trivial way to do that - you will need to find geometry data for your regions, then use data-driven styling to color them. See https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/updating-choropleth/ for an example.

Comment: Yes, probably i need to look for the geometry data and combine it with my data...Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

was having same issue searched for ages then found this lib Terraformer, (http://terraformer.io/core/#terraformercircle), one of the methods allows you to specify a long and lat point, and convert that into a circle around that point.

See my implementation below or you can also go through the docs 
http://terraformer.io/core/#terraformercircle

```
//get the Terraformer lib
var Terraformer = require("terraformer");

const getPolygonFromPoints = async => {
    //get the geoJSON
    const getPointBasedGeoJSON = await require({localresource}); //or use a fetch if it is an external resource.

    //loop over all the featues using ES6 map, to generate a new array of polygon based coordinates
    const polygonBasedGeoJSON = getPointBasedGeoJSON.features.map(d => ({
        type: "Feature",
        ...new Terraformer.Circle(
            [d.geometry.coordinates[0], d.geometry.coordinates[1]],
            500, //The radius of the circle in meters.
            5 //How many steps will be used to create the polygon that represents the circle. i.e number of poins in the polyon array
        ),
        /*
        Terraformer.Circle will retrun an object similar to this, which we need to spread into our parent object, hence the ES6 spread
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [array of polygon coordinates based on the point you referenced]
        },
        */
        point: [d.geometry.coordinates[0], d.geometry.coordinates[1]], //so that you can still reference a point
        properties: {
            //specify any properties
        }
    }));

    if (polygonBasedGeoJSON.length > 0){
        return polygonBasedGeoJSON
    }

    return []
}

//Points to Polygon collection ready for use
console.log(getPolygonFromPoints())
```

Comment: Awesome! The library seems to have moved to a new address: https://terraformer-js.github.io/core/#terraformercircle

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: I had a data regarding terrorism in csv with latitude, longitude. When i converted it to geojson I had a structure like this: 
    {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          2.8125,
          47.040182144806664
        ]
      }
    }

The question was: how I can create a map like this using this data: [terrorism_map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2icD.png)

I know that my geojson is useless in this case, but i need a way of creating map using this data. Sorry to confuse...